# Data crawling using import.io

Tags: import.io

i have crawled some data from import.io. That data are in my import.io  account. I have another import.io account. Now I want to tranfer data of my previous account to my new account. How can i do it? Is it even possible? I found no option for that

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean to port the actual data extracted, or the API you defined?

There is a way to port the APIs, although one by one:

1. Open two browser windows and log in to your OLD and NEW accounts, respectively
2. Click on an API inside the OLD account, and copy the URL
3. Paste the URL inside the NEW account window: you'll be able to "duplicate" the API in the new one. This will be a copy of the original API definition, and you will be able to run it and edit it with your new account.

[image: Duplicate button]